# How to limit specific PHP to US IPs only

Tags: php

I'm wondering if it is possible, through PHP, to only execute specific lines of PHP if the user is in the United States.  I want to include a Free Shipping graphic for the US orders over $100, but I would like to not have this show up if the user is Canadian.

Here is what I'm working with.

```
  <?php
            if ($_product->getPrice() > 100)
{
echo '<span class="shippinginfo">Free Shipping</span>';
}    
else
{
    echo '<span class="shippinginfo">Flat Rate $5.95</span>';
}
?>
```

Comment: How do you plan on handling VPNs, proxy servers, etc.?

Comment: Isn't it better to obtain country with shipping address ?

Comment: What does it matter where the person is ordering from? You should be basing the shipping decision on the ship-to address. If the address is in the US, then you can pop up a free shipping notice. Consider the case of a American ordering somethign while they're on the road in another country, but wanting the item shipped to their home. If you're doing free shipping based on IPs, you've now ripped them off.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be down voted? Phil asked a legit question that can be answered. Hey Phil add a question mark, that will make it a legit question, LOL.

Comment: Yeah, I should be basing the shipping decisions off of the address, however, the customer doesn't enter their address until they have made it to the second level of the checkout process. At that point, I don't believe my Free Shipping value proposition holds a heck of a lot of weight. 

I'm using Magento, so ideally I would have a store set up just for Canadian users, but I was looking for a simpler, less time consuming solution.

Comment: What if your IP idea actually works out in some way but then along comes a user that is in the US and needs to ship to their family in Canada. I think your best bet is to go back to the UX Design drawing table and figure out the most effective way to communicate information to the user without making them feel restricted. Maybe you can have a graphic in the header of your site that says "Free shipping within the US!" or something.

Comment: If you're not worried that some people can fake their IP and bypass certain restrictions, then the easiest way is to obtain US IP range (instead of ALL IPs, like some suggested) and match whether users' IP fits the range(s) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, 
1. filter the location using client ips,

```
$deny = array("111.111.111", "222.222.222", "333.333.333");
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
```

This will fail if the client is accessing your application using VPNs or proxy servers,

1. Find the client location using java script and pass the latitude and longitude values to server, using PHP find the geolocation of the client,

This will fail if the client browser is not enabled/allowing the location information.

```
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
  }
```

Comment: You should never rely on Javascript for purchases. You know how easy it is to fake Geolocation?

Comment: Can I nest these two solutions with an If ELSE starting with geolocation?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to have a database of all the ISPs in the world (which contains thousands of IPs), or you need to use an API such as http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Also, keep in mind, it is VERY easy to fake an IP, either by using a web proxy, an HTTP proxy, or a VPN. *You can't just trust an IP.*

For the code part, read their documentation, and once you got their country (`$country`), do this (if I understand you correctly):

```
<?php  
// ...
if($country != 'us') {
    if($_product->getPrice() > 100) {
        echo '<span class="shippinginfo">Free Shipping</span>';
    } else {
        echo '<span class="shippinginfo">Flat Rate $5.95</span>';
    }
}
// ..
?>
```

I would recommend using an API, however if you want to have a challenge (or if you truly have a **lot** of traffic), you could download a database such as the one from [here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/), and do the IP to country conversion yourself. And remember, you are never 100% sure that a user is from a US even if they seem to have a US IP.

Answer (score 0):

You need a GeoIP database. There are a whole stack of them available -- here's [one result I got from google](http://www.geoip.co.uk/), but there's plenty of others; find one that suits you best (some are free, some you have to pay for; some just have country data, others have town data; some are online APIs, some are downloadable databases; some are more up-to-date than others; etc etc).

The issues you'll have are:

- Keeping the data up-to-date -- IP addresses are not tied to a given location. The database relies on data about the ownership of each address block, and where that owner (ie the local ISP) is using it. IP addresses do change ownership and location fairly often, and your database will very quickly start giving incorrect results if you don't keep it up-to-date. And even an up-to-date DB can be wrong; the locations of IPs aren't published formally, so the database maintainers have to keep tabs on changes manually. It's not uncommon for them to miss some.
- You will get incorrect results from users connecting via a VPN or using a proxy server. There's nothing you can do about this: you just have to accept that it is possible to be in one location while your IP address appears to be somewhere else.

The message from the above is that you can do it, but it is not guaranteed to be correct, so use it, but **do not rely on it**.

You should therefore, offer your users a way to get around it and specify their country manually.